# Is there a discount on train tickets for people older than a given age in the Netherlands?

Tags: trains, tickets, netherlands, senior-travel

I am helping a friend to plan a trip in the Netherlands. He is 68 years old. Is there some discount on the train like in Belgium?

Comment: Some general info that might help: http://seniortravel.about.com/od/seniortravelbargains/f/EuropeTrainDisc.htm

Comment: @MeNoTalk That's a great tip!

Comment: @MeNoTalk I encourage you to answer this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27040/are-there-any-website-or-other-resource-that-lists-discounts-or-special-conditio

Answer (score 7):

Not really, at least for NS (the main operator in the country). As far as I know, the only things seniors can get are

- 7 day travel passes (called “*Keuzedagen*”), if they already have an *[Altijd Voordeel](http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/producten/abonnementen/altijd-voordeel.html)* or *[Dal Voordeel](http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/producten/abonnementen/dal-voordeel.html)* discount card. You can't buy a single day travel pass at the discounted price, you have to buy 7 of them and you need to have a yearly discount card to benefit from the offer (it's not valid with a monthly discount card).
- Discounted prices on passes like *Dal Vrij* or *Weekend Vrij*. Those are also yearly passes.

None of this seems relevant for visitors and, in fact, the info is apparently not even available in the English-language part of the website.

There are a few other train operators, mostly in the north and east of the country but I don't know about those.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was about to type :)

Comment: yes. There used to be, years ago, government sponsored travel for residents with a special senior citizen card (which gave discounted entry not just to public transport but also museums and events), but that entire program was dropped and never replaced. It was for residents/citizens only anyway, not for visitors.